# How to find exact response time in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-time

How to find the exact time taken for my web page to load using jmeter? Since i am getting 3 sec as response time but manually it takes more than that to load the page.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you didn't check `Retrieve All Embedded Resources` box in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)) so your request basically gets only HTTP response but doesn't resolve any nested content (images, styles, scripts, fonts) which have much more "weight"

[image: JMeter Embedded Resources]

See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) article to learn more about how to work with these "embedded resources"

Another inconsistency can be caused by JMeter not executing [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) requests, i.e. if your application relies on JavaScript-generated requests and rendering their responses. JMeter is not a browser and it doesn't automatically execute JavaScript found in the HTML response so if this is the case you will need to manually add these requests to your Test Plan (or record them using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)) and measure cumulative time via i.e. [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller).

Answer (score 0):

As a follow on to Dmitri's post, take the page in question and examine it using the developer tools of your chosen browser.  Examine very specifically the split between client side actions (JavaScript, Rendering, Painting, ...) and server side requests.  In all likelihood you are timing A with Jmeter and B with your eyes

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please tell me how to get the chart result that you have shared above?

Comment: Chrome.  Developers Tools.  Performance Tab.  Similar information is available across all browser manufacturers